# How to reposition the axis title in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to reposition (e.g., move up by 10px) the x-axis label of this chart

```
  ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x=carb, y=..count..),data=mtcars)
```

I thought I could use `vjust` but as mentioned in this [github issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1252), the only way to shift the x-label vertically is by using `margin`:

```
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(margin=margin(0,0,-10,0)))
```

However, margin produces something very different than a simple repositioning of the x-title, in that it resizes the chart too. I could I simply move the x-label instead?

Comment: Save your plot to a desired size. Increase margin(x, unit = "cm'). Save new plot with size + x.

Answer (score -1):

You could do it this way

```
 ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x=carb, y=..count..),data=mtcars)+ 
    theme(axis.title.x=element_text(margin=margin(-5,0,0,0)))
```

Just change the numbers until you get a satisfying result.

Comment: Right, which is what I said I did.